# Visual studio razor views putting brackets on last line instead of newline on format document

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2019

In visual studio 2019 when I go to format document under Edit -> Advanced it puts the bracket on the last line of code instead of a new line? It never did this before so how can I get it back to the old formatting?

**Don't Want**

[image: Image showing curly bracket at end of line with ending </div> tag]

**Want**

[image: Image showing curly bracket at beginning of next line on its own]

Comment: Resharper is not installed

Comment: 2019 visual studio